# Access VBA cascade methods

Tags: ms-access, vba

How can I cascade methods for a custom class?

What I am working on is a custom class to work with dates.

I feed the class a date as a property. Then I would like to return the date based on the method associated. For example:

```
InputDate.AdjustToFirst
```

So if I input 5/15/2015 the above would return 5/1/2015.

Likewise could I do:

```
InputDate.AdjustToFirst.ReduceOneYear
```

so if input 5/15/2015 the return would be 5/1/2014.

Further

```
InputDate.ReduceOneYear
```

5/15/2015 would return 5/15/2014.

I know about DateSerial, I am just trying to learn how to do the above. The idea is similar to VBs `variable.ToString` method.

Comment: This is typically called method chaining, and is made possible by returning either the current or a new instance of your class (with the expected internal state) as the result of any instance method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have the function simply return a new object ([*method chaining*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining) as mentioned by Fred Wilson already). Here a small example of a class I called `MyDate`:

```
Private m_date As Date

Public Sub Init(ByVal d As Date)
m_date = d
End Sub

Public Function ToString() As String
ToString = m_date
End Function

Public Function AddYear(y As Integer) As MyDate
Dim newDate As MyDate
Set newDate = New MyDate
newDate.Init (DateAdd("yyyy", y, m_date))
Set AddYear = newDate
End Function

Public Function AddMonth(m As Integer) As MyDate
Dim newDate As MyDate
Set newDate = New MyDate
newDate.Init (DateAdd("m", m, m_date))
Set AddMonth = newDate
End Function
```

Now you can use `AddYear` and `AddMonth` as a chain function:

```
Dim d As MyDate
Set d = New MyDate
d.Init (Now)
MsgBox d.AddYear(2).AddMonth(4).ToString()
```

Comment: I think I finally get it. The piece I was missing is the ToString method you show here. I was having a hard time figuring out how to get the data out if the method was returning a class. Now I understand. Let the flood gates open now.